# Avoid inheritance of plugins configurations by external modules

Tags: maven

Suppose I have the three following maven modules :

- parent
- heir (submodule of parent, parent is its parent)
- extern (other project, parent is its parent)

I would like to configure plugins only for parent and its submodules (parent and heir in my example) without any side effect for external projects (extern in this case).

parent defines a plugin in pluginManagement, for example :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>hello, heir</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>echo</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>Hello, heir!</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately, this plugin configuration will have a side effect on extern.
See, if extern defines the following, the above configuration will apply to him :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    ...
</plugin>
```

Now, how can change my project structure or pom configuration so that :

1. I can build my whole project from a single command on one pom
2. I can deploy my whole project from a single command on one pom
3. I can define plugins for internal use only (parent pom and its submodules) / An external project will not inherit from these plugins
4. Said plugins are still inherited from internal plugins

?

Comment: Do you have a full example setup of this on github or alike?

Comment: I came to the same conclusion as J Fabian Meier. I'll test his solution. If it doesn't work, I'll upload my PoC. It currently sits on a VM behind a VPN, so I won't do this if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the hierarchy to

- external-parent
- parent
- submodules

Comment: It's indeed the solution, but it could be a bit more elaborate. Furthermore, I'd like to point out that it is possible to set the intermediary / internal parent, maven wise, in the same directory as the submodules, at the condition that the submodules set the "relativePath" in their "parent" statement. That's particularly useful when you don't want to move 220 modules and create tons of git conflicts.